# Efficient way to run a large list of python script without iteration

Tags: python, list, win32com

I have a large list of python script such as follows:

```
My_list=['PivotTable.PivotFields("time").PivotItems(item).Visible=Boolean']
```

where the `item=1,2,...,n` & `Boolean= True or False`

I used the following lines of code, but for n=1000000, it took to much time.

```
for item in range(n):
   exec(My_list[item])
```

The code above, filter a pivot table in terms of input time interval in the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by conducting the following steps. I briefly explain these steps, maybe someone finds it useful:
First) Instead of filtering “time” data, I created an array (n×1), in pandas called “filter_column” which its elements were [False, True],

Second) Then, I added the data into the last column of excel file (called “Date/Time”) by the following codes:

```
ws = wb.Worksheets(getSheetName[sheet_index])
allData = ws.UsedRange
getNumCols = allData.Columns.Count
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, getNumCols), ws.Cells(1, getNumCols)).Value = 'Date/Time Filter'

getNumRows = allData.Rows.Count
First_cell = ws.Cells(2, getNumCols)
Last_cell = ws.Cells(getNumRows, getNumCols)
SelectedRange = ws.Range(First_cell, Last_cell)
SelectedRange.Value = filter_column_df.values.tolist()
```

Third) I filtered “time” data through its proxy variable, “Date/Time” data. There was m<n cases which I had to take their check away in “time” data, but I just unchecked one case (False data) for “Date/Time” data as follows:

```
 PivotTable.PivotFields("Date/Time Filter").PivotItems("0").Visible = False
```

Fourth) After creation of pivot table and pivot chart, I deleted “Date/Time” data from initial worksheet (the worksheet which I added filter_column” data) as follows:

```
  wb.active = sheet_index+1
  First_cell = ws.Cells(1, getNumCols)
  Last_cell = ws.Cells(getNumRows, getNumCols)
  SelectedRange = ws.Range(First_cell, Last_cell)
  SelectedRange.Value = ''
```